# Google Maps - Multiple instances of same marker due to zoom

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi I have a scenario where say I have a marker at a given location if the user zooms out so that the country the marker is on is shown twice, you see the marker twice.

I was wondering if it is possible to remove one instance of that marker so that only one version of it is displayed at a time.

At present it then breaks an overlay hover behaviour because the maps api can't determine where to place the overlay as there are 2 instances of the same marker on the screen at a given point in time.

Thanks

Comment: Can you place the code how you create your marker?

Comment: http://www.messagesforjapan.com/messages/map/

If you see here and scroll the map so two copies of say Australia are in view and try and hover over the marker on the copy of the country on your right

The same happens with a stock out of the box overlay as the marker using the overlay method

Thanks for the reply

Comment: `google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {

                    // Get screen xy

                    var pos = self.latLngPixel(this.getPosition());

     
     // Create an overlay

     var overlay = self.createOverlay( this.message, pos );

     
     // Add it to the dom
     $(self.mapCanvas).after(overlay);

                });`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like that might be a bug (or at least unintended behavior).

A google.maps.Marker with an SVG icon is only rendered on the center instance of the tiles:

```
var SvgMarker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    icon: {
      path: 'M 0,0 C -2,-20 -10,-22 -10,-30 A 10,10 0 1,1 10,-30 C 10,-22 2,-20 0,0 z M -2,-30 a 2,2 0 1,1 4,0 2,2 0 1,1 -4,0',
      fillColor: "red",
      fillOpacity: 1,
      strokeColor: '#000',
      strokeWeight: 2,
      scale: 1
    },
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-30.4419, -72.1419)
  });
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/017rk2u9/1/)

[image: SVG Icons on Map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 0,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: map.getCenter()
  });
  var SvgMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    icon: {
      path: 'M 0,0 C -2,-20 -10,-22 -10,-30 A 10,10 0 1,1 10,-30 C 10,-22 2,-20 0,0 z',
      fillColor: "red",
      fillOpacity: 1,
      strokeColor: '#000',
      strokeWeight: 2,
      scale: 1
    },
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-30.4419, -122.1419)
  });
  var SvgMarker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    icon: {
      path: 'M 0,0 C -2,-20 -10,-22 -10,-30 A 10,10 0 1,1 10,-30 C 10,-22 2,-20 0,0 z M -2,-30 a 2,2 0 1,1 4,0 2,2 0 1,1 -4,0',
      fillColor: "red",
      fillOpacity: 1,
      strokeColor: '#000',
      strokeWeight: 2,
      scale: 1
    },
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-30.4419, -72.1419)
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: but with a png marker it replicates.. hmm I'll try svg